# Error message when URL is equal to aspected

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I´m running this test and when it comes to the part to assert the URL contents I got this error message. What causes this? And why? Thanks in advance.

```
Running:  Click 
 √ Element <#azercell_language_selector> was visible after 2482 milliseconds.
 √ Element <#azercell_language_selector option:nth-child(2)> was visible after 1
845 milliseconds.
 × Testing if the URL contains "http://oyun.azercell.com/ru?lang=ru".  - expecte
d "http://oyun.azercell.com/ru?lang=ru" but got: http://oyun.azercell.com/?lang=ru
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test you have an assertion that page url is

```
http://oyun.azercell.com/ru?lang=ru
```

but you got

```
http://oyun.azercell.com/?lang=ru
```

So your test fail.

It from your side this two url's are same, you can remove this assertion in you test code.

Comment: If i remove this assertion I can´t assure that the click event is done and the new url is opened

Comment: So check if url changed

Comment: The url has not changed

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see your assertion to validate the URL is failing. You are expected a url

```
http://oyun.azercell.com/ru?lang=ru
```

But you received below url which is missing text '**ru**' after '**.com/**'

```
http://oyun.azercell.com/?lang=ru
```

Your assertion failure is causing this issue I believe

Comment: Just checked the url, definitely is "http://oyun.azercell.com/?lang=ru" but thanks for trying

Comment: Not you, it was aimed at @Rita

Comment: @marwaha.ks, Hi, already fixed this. The url was correct it was an extra blank space that was causing the test to fail.